# What is the proper prefix for a rabbi?

Tags: grammar-dikduk

What are the different prefixes for a rabbi, what are their differences, and when is it appropriate to use them?

Example: ר',הרב, מרן, הרה"ח, הרה"ת, הרה"ג, הרה"ק

(This question differs from previously asked similar questions, since this question is asking when it is applicable to use which suffix)

Comment: https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=20022&pgnum=133